# Latex equations exported in markdown

Tags: emacs, latex, r-markdown, org-mode, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to render latex equations on github.com by exporting markdown of a document in org-mode. The raw latex gets written to the exported file so the equations don't render on the site. Is there a way to get the generated images to appear as markdown file imports? In other words, insert the generated file name where the raw latex appears, so instead of

```
\begin{equation*}
x_{norm}^{(i)}=\frac{x^{(i)}-x_{min}}{x_{max}-x_{min}}
\end{equation*}
```

the generated image is inserted:

```
[ltxpng/machine-learning_fc5c92782db4a6699428aad7685ff014040f4342.png]
```